# É necessário usar o ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) no WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Por fim de estudos estou criando um tema WordPress, em fase de finalização.

Ao longo da criação me deparei com o seguinte código, chamamos de "**código1**":

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}
```

O qual impede acesso direto aos meus arquivos .php diretamente pela URL.

Este chamamos de "**código2**", encontrado no *wp-config.php*:

```
/** Caminho absoluto para o diretório WordPress. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
   define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

Abaixo a minha pergunta:

Então seria recomendado adicionar o "**código1**" nas paginas do tema WordPress? ou ele tem a mesma função do do "**código2**" encontrado no *wp-config.php*

Me veio está duvida apos ver o "**código1**" dentro de um tema WordPress já pronto, o qual continha o "**código1**" dentro de todos os arquivos .php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como a constante `ABSPATH` é definida logo no início do processo de carregamento do Wordpress, é garantido que ela existirá quando seu tema for carregado normalmente. Agora, imagine que alguém tente acessar uma URL assim:

`https://seusite.com/wp-content/themes/seutema/functions.php`

O functions.php geralmente contém chamadas de funções definidas fora dele, como `add_action()`. Quando o tema é carregado pelo WP, essas funções serão declaradas antes do functions.php ser carregado. Já no acesso direto, essas funções não estarão definidas e a tentativa de chamá-las irá gerar um erro. Esse erro, se for exibido, vai expor o caminho absoluto do arquivo no servidor. Algo assim:

> **Fatal error:** Call to undefined function add_action() in /home/usuario/public_html/wp-content/themes/seutema/functions.php on line 1

Essa informação adicional – `/home/usuario/public_html`, nas mãos de alguém mal-intencionado, pode ajudar a explorar alguma vulnerabilidade do seu código ou do seu ambiente.